Having an issue while working with an delimiter to convert the user_input to list or set
I want to delete the elements from the main_list and the elements are taken from the user as user_input where all the part of the code executed perfectly but the elements are not deleted from the main_list there are no error messages so I do not know where the problem lied.
the code is-
def convert_input_to_set(user_input, delimiter=None):
    try:
        elements = set(user_input.split(delimiter)) if delimiter else set(user_input.split())
        return {int(element) if element.isdigit() else element for element in elements}
    except Exception as e:
       print(f"\nError: {e}. Make sure you provide a valid list. Let's try this again.\n")
    return set()

def remove_element(main_list):
    while True:
        print("Use comma ',', space ' ', pipe '|', or semicolon ';' to separate the elements.\n")

        user_input = input("Enter the elements you want to remove from the main list: ")
        elements = convert_input_to_set(user_input)
    
        print(f"\nYour elements to remove: {', '.join(map(str, elements))}. Does this look correct?")
        confirmation = input("\nType 'y' or 'yes' to confirm, or 'n' or 'no' to retry: ").lower()
    
        if confirmation in {"yes", "y"}:
            main_list[:] = [element for element in main_list if element not in elements]
            print("\nThe elements have been removed from the main list.\n")
            break
        else:
            print("Okay, let's try again.")
    
    return main_list

main_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

main_list = remove_element(main_list)

print(main_list)

When I change the approach to convert the user_input into set, where I changed this code elements = set(user_input.split(delimiter)) if delimiter else set(user_input.split()) to this elements = user_input.replace(',', ' ').replace(';', ' ').replace('|', ' ').split() the code ran perfectly. My Question is, What was the issue I was having while running this code elements = set(user_input.split(delimiter)) if delimiter else set(user_input.split())

I'm going to guess that the user entered something like 1, 2, 3 , which has BOTH a comma and a space as the delimiter.  if you call .split() on that, the commas are kept, so the input items end up looking like "1," which is not in the list main list.

You could use re.split() to be more flexible about the delimiter.

@JohnGordon No, The line on this command line is printed as Your elements to remove: 1,2,3. Does this look correct? for this code elements = set(user_input.split(delimiter)) if delimiter else set(user_input.split()) and for another one the elements are prined as Your elements to remove: 1, 2, 3. Does this look correct?. I have no idea where the "problem lies". so i have changed many part of the code and tried many other things and when I changed this part of the code it work. don't know why? So I want to why code worked what was the issue in the first place.

string.split() doesn't work as you expect.
If no argument is passed to the split function, the default value None is used, so "hello".split() will return ["hello"] not ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']. You should use list(string) for that.
But, there is another issue in your code. You are building a set from the list while converting digits to integers and keeping the others as they are. For example, if you enter "1|2", it will return {"1", "2", "|"}, which is probably not what you want. You should only add to the set if the character is a digit.
So you can use this:
def convert_input_to_set(user_input, delimiter=None):
    try:
        elements = set(user_input.split(delimiter) if delimiter else list(user_input))
        return { int(element) for element in elements if element.isdigit() }
    except Exception as e:
       print(f"\nError: {e}. Make sure you provide a valid list. Let's try this again.\n")
    return set()

Edit:
If you want to split multiple characters like "apple" or a 2-digit number like 12, you can replace all delimiters with some single delimiter and then split.
like:
def convert_input_to_set(user_input, delimiter=' '):
    try:
        for char in [',', '|', ';']:
            user_input = user_input.replace(char, delimiter)
        elements = set(user_input.split(delimiter))
        return { int(element) if element.isdigit() else element for element in elements }
    except Exception as e:
       print(f"\nError: {e}. Make sure you provide a valid list. Let's try this again.\n")
    return set()


can you please edit this code so it can support strings as well. For eg. I have a list ['apple', 'pineapple', 'grapes', 'strawberry', '1', '2', '3'] if I want to remove apple from this list how can I do it
